# Binding data from function to bool variable

Tags: c#

I want to implement a mechanism that change bool variable to true any time I call to set function (I have couple of setters functions). Sample Code:

```
private bool isSomethingChanged = false;

public void SetName(string _name)
{
    // change name
}
```

I don't want to write: `isSomethingChanged = true;` at the end of all setters functions.
I want it to happen automatically. Is it possible ?

Comment: What do you mean "automatically"??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First - it's not enough to simply set `isSomethingChanged` to true at the end of setter - you should also verify that something really changed. E.g.

```
public void SetName(string _name)
{
    if (name == _name) // check
       return;   

    name = _name;
    isSomethingChanged = true;
}
```

Back to solving your problem - there is no built-in feature to set some variable automatically when any of methods was called. You can use code generation for that. E.g. you can use AOP framework PostSharp. Here is implementation of `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface with this framework, which does almost same as you want: [AOP Implementation of INotifyPropertyChanged](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/35368/AOP-Implementation-of-INotifyPropertyChanged). The only difference is you should set variable value instead of raising event.

Comment: Couldn't you rewrite it a little less simple? Like: `public void SetName(string _name) { if (name != _name) { name = _name; isSomethingChanged = true; }`. I just like to avoid 'useless' `return` statements. :)

Comment: @Abbas actually there is no difference. But I like [guard conditions](http://refactoring.com/catalog/replaceNestedConditionalWithGuardClauses.html) for simple single-level code identation, also I prefer positive comparision (equals) to negative comparisons (not equals) - but that matter of taste maybe :)

Comment: I agree with you @SergeyBerezovskiy. The code Abbas suggested is, to me, less readable, because you could potentially end up with a huge nested block. For me the `} } } } } } } } }`-end of a method is horrible..

Comment: @Default / SergeyBerezovskiy Ok, I agree with both of you. This might indeed be cleaner. :)